# expo ImageManipulator returning [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expo.ImageManipulator.manipulate')]

Tags: react-native, undefined

for some reason

```
const manipResult = await ImageManipulator.manipulate(
    image,
    [{ resize: { width: 640, height: 480 } }],
    { format: 'jpg' }
);
```

returns [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expo.ImageManipulator.manipulate')]
which is weird because it worked one time and then this started to be returned by react native whenever it runs this line of code. so basically what im trying to do is resize the image and then send it to an api but for some reason it won't work and keeps giving this error even though data.uri isn't undefined

whole code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { Camera, CameraType } from 'expo-camera';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import Button from './src/components/Button';
import axios from 'axios'
import { Buffer } from "buffer";
import * as FS from "expo-file-system";
import { ImageManipulator } from 'expo';

export default function App() {
  const [hasCameraPermission, setHasCameraPermission] = useState(null);
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);
  const [flash, setFlash] = useState(Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off);
  const cameraRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
      const cameraStatus = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
      setHasCameraPermission(cameraStatus.status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  const takePicture = async () => {
    if (cameraRef) {
      try {
        const data = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync();
        console.log(data);
        const manipResult = await ImageManipulator.manipulate(
          data.uri,
          [{ resize: { width: 640, height: 480 } }],
          { format: 'jpg' }
      );
        setImage(manipResult0);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  };

  uriToBase64 = async (uri) => {
    let base64 = await FS.readAsStringAsync(uri, {
      encoding: FS.EncodingType.Base64,
    });
    return base64;
  };

  toServer = async (mediaFile) => {
    const url = "api url";
    let response = await FS.uploadAsync(url, mediaFile.uri, {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "image/jpeg",
      },
      httpMethod: "POST",
      uploadType: FS.FileSystemUploadType.BINARY_CONTENT,
    });

    console.log(response);
 
  };
  
  const savePicture = async () => {
    if(image) {
      try {
        const asset= await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(image);
        await toServer({
          type:"image",
          base64: uriToBase64(image),
          uri: image,
        });
        setImage(null);
        console.log('saved successfully');
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  };

  if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {!image ? (
        <Camera
          style={styles.camera}
          type={type}
          ref={cameraRef}
          flashMode={flash}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              paddingHorizontal: 30,
            }}
          >
            <Button
              title=""
              icon="retweet"
              onPress={() => {
                setType(
                  type === CameraType.back ? CameraType.front : CameraType.back
                );
              }}
            />
            <Button
              onPress={() =>
                setFlash(
                  flash === Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off
                    ? Camera.Constants.FlashMode.on
                    : Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off
                )
              }
              icon="flash"
              color={flash === Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off ? 'gray' : '#fff'}
            />
          </View>
        </Camera>
      ) : (
        <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={styles.camera} />
      )}

      <View style={styles.controls}>
        {image ? (
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              paddingHorizontal: 50,
            }}
          >
            <Button
              title="Re-take"
              onPress={() => setImage(null)}
              icon="retweet"
            />
          
            <Button title="Save" onPress={savePicture} icon="check" />
          </View>
        ) : (
          <Button title="Take a picture" onPress={takePicture} icon="camera" />
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    padding: 8,
  },
  controls: {
    flex: 0.5,
  },
  button: {
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 6,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#E9730F',
    marginLeft: 10,
  },
  camera: {
    flex: 5,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  topControls: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```